# svg2pdf.js doc.svg() add and save issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

i am trying to migrate to the newer version of svg2pdf.js(1.5.0 -> 2.2.2) and jspdf(2.0.0 -> 2.5.1). Project is on React(v16.9.0, node v12.22.12) Updated the dep version but i can not get it work as before.

follow the documentation (https://github.com/yWorks/svg2pdf.js) still does not work.

current implementation is:

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
import 'svg2pdf.js'
...
const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [width, height]);

//get the template to be drawn on the page
const blankSvg = document.querySelector('#svg-pdf-headFoot').contentDocument.querySelector('svg'); 


await pdf.svg(blankSvg, { x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200 }) //just random dimensions
..

//finally
pdf.save(filename);
```

After executing the downloadPdf() i get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.multiply is not a function
    at E.y.matrixMult (jspdf.es.min.js:86:1)
    at _ (svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1)
    at e.computeNodeTransformCore (svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1)
    at e.computeNodeTransform (svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1)
    at e.<anonymous> (svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1)
    at svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1
    at Object.next (svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1)
    at svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at c (svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1)
    at e.render (svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1)
    at e.<anonymous> (svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1)
    at svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1
    at Object.next (svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1)
    at svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at c (svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1)
    at e.render (svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1)
    at svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1
    at svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1
    at Object.next (svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1)
    at s (svg2pdf.es.min.js:41:1)
```

Could not manage to find a solution.

Has anyone encountered this issue?
Not sure what am i doing wrong.

Tried exaclty as in the documentation, with no luck.

The pdf is not being created, nor downloaded.